# How do I untrust a computer with Google two-factor authentication?

Tags: security, google-account, multi-factor-auth

I use Google's two factor authentication to send my phone text messages with a string of 6 numbers every time I log into a computer that isn't mine. It has worked well so far until today.

Today, I took too long to enter the code, which would be fine normally... except I clicked through faster than I should have and realized shortly after that the "*trust this computer*" box was checked the second time through. I took a look through the options for my Google account and saw no obvious place to revoke the trust.

This is absolutely not a computer I want trusted for any extended amount of time.

**How do I untrust a computer from Google's two-factor authentication?**

Comment: Sad to see no answer that is correct for the current Google Account application.

Comment: In 2018 Check !!! this tut https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-remove-trusted-devices-from-google-gmail-account/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Clear the browser's cookies](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1056283&answer=1185133#remembercomp)** (and perhaps cache/history).

> #### ['Trust this computer' option doesn’t work](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1056283&answer=1185133#remembercomp)
>
> For computers you trust, Google recommends you select the "Trust this computer" option when you are asked for a verification code. When you check this box, you won’t have to enter a code every time you sign in to your account from that computer.
>
> **This feature uses a cookie to remember your browser when you sign in. If you’re still being asked to enter a code despite selecting the “Trust this computer” option, this might be because your browser is set to delete cookies after a certain period of time,** or is set to delete cookies every time you quit the browser. You may also be manually clearing cookies from your browser. *(emphasis added)*

Comment: Ahhhh... So it's cookie-based? This is good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any references for this? It’s just a gut feeling, but I don’t think it’s just cookie-based.

Comment: @Alex: Proof by experimentation; also, [this Google Help page](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1056283&answer=1185133#remembercomp).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the updated info.

Comment: Updated link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en

Comment: Wait ... so all you need to turn a computer into a trusted computer is a cookie? Shouldn't this be managed server-side in a more secure fashion? If this is managed on the server end, they why can't the user SEE what computers have access as "trusted" devices.

Comment: @Aaron, what other method do you suggest of identifying a specific trusted computer?

Comment: This is NOT the right answer.  Verified this does not work on Safari 10.1.1

Comment: @AaronKlap it is twofold. I believe Google creates a token (similar to an Oauth token) that is stored within the cookie that marks the device as trusted. If you go into your Google Account under Trusted Devices and revoke that trust, it deletes the server side key that the token unlocks, thereby removing the access for that computer even though it still has the cookie.

Answer (score 15):

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838):

> **Removing trusted computers from your list**
>
> You can remove computers from your set of trusted computers at any
>   time. To do so, sign in to your account and go to your 2-step
>   verification settings page. Under the “Advanced” section, you’ll have
>   the choice to remove the computer you’re using at the time or all
>   other computers. If you choose to remove other computers from your
>   trusted list, those computers will automatically sign out of your
>   account, and you’ll be prompted for a verification code next time you
>   try to sign in from them.

The  2-step verification settings page is at https://google.com/accounts/SmsAuthConfig

Comment: I like this option much better as it seems far more secure. It is nice having the ability to unregister devices, but I wonder why a user can't SEE what devices are registered. If some unknown device keeps being added as a "registered device" even after unregistered all of them repeatedly, it would be nice to know about this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also useful is this help article: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en

Comment: This technically should not be the answer either, Tim's comment should be, since Julie's answer gives false directions (there is no "Advanced" section).  You cannot remove a specific computer, but rather only ALL.  Tim Malone's link confirms this.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

Account > Security > 2-step Verification Setting > Registered Computers > Require Codes

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: This also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Visit (https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity), it should prompt you to login to your Google Account if you aren't already. Click on "Review Devices" to get the full list and click on an individual device and click "Delete" to log out and remove access from that device.